# How can my Ultimate Performance power plan activated everytime i open games

Tags: gaming, task-scheduler

I tried using Task Scheduler to **trigger Ultimate Performance power plan** activated when opening games but it doesn't seem to work
I don't want to use any third-party apps

Answer (score 0):

Easily done through two .REG files, one to set *Ultimate Performance*, the other to revert to your current power scheme. The power scheme is set at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\
```

in *Value* REG_SZ `ActivePowerScheme`.

[image: Registry: Active Power Scheme]

The *Value* is defined immediately below; e.g., for GUID `381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`,

[image: {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} description]

- Right-click *Key* `PowerSchemes*.
- Select *Export*.
- Choose a filename indicating the *current* scheme, e.g., *Balanced.reg*, in my example.

Using the *Control Panel*, switch to *Ultimate Performance*
Again, *Export* the file, with a name like *UltPerf.reg*.

Now you can double-click one of the files to select a power scheme.

However, if that's too much effort, create a batch file that first calls `regedit.exe "{path}\UltPerf.reg"`, then start the game, and finally calls `regedit.exe "{path}\Balanced.reg"`, which will run after the game closes. *Viola!*